# Can't build project using mongodb c++ driver with MSVC

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost

I'm trying to build the following sample c++ code with Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors with the code, but during building I'm getting the following errors:
[image]

[image]

I've built the the driver according to this:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/appveyor.yml

System info:
-Win10 
-Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3
-using Boost 1.60.0 64-bit
-using CMake 3.7.0
-using Git 2.10.2

Also, I have added the following include libraries to the project:
-bsoncxx
-mongocxx
-libmongoc
-libbson
-boost
And the following linker libraries:
-boost 64-bit lib
-mongo driver libraries

If anyone could tell me what's wrong with my build it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of mongocxx are you building?

Comment: The latest version from [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver), I think it's version 3.0.3.

Comment: That looks like an MSVC issue.  For example, see [this post](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1835) or [this Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=MSVC%20INTMAX_MAX%20undeclared%20identifier).  Once you get ratio and chrono building properly, I suspect the mongocxx bits will work.

Comment: Awesome, the first link helped get rid of the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the chrono and ratio errors by adding the " __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS " line to Project Properties\C/C++\Preprocessor\Preprocessor Definitions. (thanks @xdg for the help)

For the other mongocxx errors, the problems were: 
1. I was trying to build a 32-bit project using 64-bit BOOST libraries
 -got this fixed by creating a new 64-bit project
2. had to include the bsoncxx.lib and mongocxx.lib files in Project Properties\Linker\Input\Additional Dependencies

After these steps the project build was successful, but I got errors during runtime because the bsoncxx, mongocxx, libmongoc-1.0 and libbson-1.0 dlls were missing, I got that fixed simply by copying the above mentioned dlls to the project release folder.